# Calling a method of a user control from parent form

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, listview

i have a problem accessing a method of my Usercontrol.

My setup is the following:

I have a MainForm called "SearchForm" and  a second Form called "ShowSequence" (it gets called from SearchForm).

The ShowSequence Form has a UserControl named "SequenceList" attached to it with a WPF ListView on it. The ListView content is filled when the ShowSequence Form loads.

Now when i click a button in my SearchForm i want to refresh the ListView of my SequenceList (UserControl) on the ShowSequence Form.

Because i am creating several of those ShowSequence Forms (as instances) i will have to find the ShowSequence Form i need. I will identify it by name and call MyMethod():

```
if  (System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["NameofForm"] != null)
{
    (System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["NameofForm"] as ShowSequence).MyMethod();
}
```

So MyMethod on ShowSequence Form should now access a Method called Refresh() in the SequenceList class (UserControl) and start the refresh of my ListView.

Show Sequence Form.......

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    SequenceList.Refresh(); // error
}
```

That is not possible. The system tells me to create an object reference to access the Refresh() Method because its not static.

So I used this :

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    SequencList SeqLi = new SequenceList();
    SeqLi.Refresh();
}
```

But when I do so I don't get my SequenceList.ListView that is running in an opened instance of ShowSequence Form updated. I guess because I created an
object of SequenceList instead of calling the Method on the opened Form? Or am i wrong?

Comment: Thanks for editing SwiftArchitekt.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found a solution.

I have to use the object of (UserControl) SeuquenceList that i created in SequenceView at creation.

That does the trick :)